# How to redirect to a certain location in a page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have a blogging application with comments. 
Currently, the comments controller has a standard create action

```
def create    
  @comment = current_user.build(params[:comment])
  respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
    format.html { redirect_to @comment.post }
  end
end
```

After creation, the user is redirected to the blog post for which the comment was made. How do I redirect lower down in the page, to where the new comment is?

**posts/show.html.erb**

```
<div id="post_show">
  <%= @post.content %>
  <%= render @post.comments %>
</div>
```

**comments/_comment.html.erb**

```
<div id="comment_partial">
  <%= comment.content %>
</div>
```

Is there something I can add to my HTML, then reference in my controller? Do I need to "save" the location somehow? Thanks for helping out a newbie!

Comment: If your comment container has a unique id such as `<div id="comment_12345">` then you can append #comment_12345 to the url and this will make sure whatever element with the id `comment_12345` will be scrolled to on the page.

Comment: Hi @Christopher, this is working perfectly for me when redirecting to a named path. However, I'm having trouble using this with redirect_to :back, and put up a new question. Would appreciate any input.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793736/how-to-add-an-anchor-to-redirect-to-back

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `anchor` option in path helpers, e.g.

```
redirect_to post_path(@comment.post, anchor: 'some-id')
```

Comment: Thanks @Ahmad. I did exactly that with `<div id="comment_<%= comment.id %>">` and `post_path(@comment.post, anchor: "comment_#{@comment.id}")`

Comment: HI @Ahmad, this is working perfectly for me when redirecting to a named path. However, I'm having trouble using this with `redirect_to :back`, and put up a new question. Would appreciate any input.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793736/how-to-add-an-anchor-to-redirect-to-back

Comment: thanks, this is the exact answer that i am looking for.