# Can I redirect_to a specific location within a view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, methods, path, controller

Is it possible to redirect_to a specific location within view in a rails application through a controller action? For example, upon creating a record, I would like to use redirect to to point to `<div id="default">` within my root path as opposed to simply `redirect_to root_path`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect to a certain location in a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791556/how-to-redirect-to-a-certain-location-in-a-page)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `anchor` in your redirect:

```
<%= redirect_to root_path, anchor: ‘some_anchor’ %>
```